# How to set age of user in Applovin SDK if my game can have both children and adults playing it

Tags: mobile, ads, privacy-policy, applovin

I am using Applovin SDK for ads in my word game and when I read Applovin’s privacy policy, it says:

> You must set appropriate age-related flag values for end users via the
> AppLovin SDK and/or related APIs, as required under any applicable
> laws or app store policies.  As explained below, AppLovin does not
> knowingly collect personal information from children or serve ads to
> children.

My word game is a generic game for all ages. I dont specifically ask the user their age, email or any PII since I dont need any of it. I dont really want to ask the user for their age at the start of the game - I havent seen most games do anything like this. How am I supposed to set the flags without asking all this information explicitly from the user.

My app is sometimes getting rejected by Google Play because I have targeted multiple age groups from 6 through adult and some unsuitable ad was shown apparently. The content of my game is simple and clean - there is nothing in it that is unsuitable for children so I have no reason to restrict the age of the user.

Are there some default values that the OS can give me and I can pull that info through some API? I am not clear how to setAgeRestrictedUser and hasUserConsent without explicitly asking all of this. I am afraid that if I ask all these questions at the start of the app, some of the users will surely drop out even before opening the app.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Per Applovin GuideLINE :-

[https://dash.applovin.com/documentation/mediation/android/getting-started/privacy#:~:text=You%20must%20review%20the%20age,and%20users%20of%20unknown%20age](https://dash.applovin.com/documentation/mediation/android/getting-started/privacy#:%7E:text=You%20must%20review%20the%20age,and%20users%20of%20unknown%20age).

⇒ If your app is designed for everyone, including children:
You must adhere to Google Play’s Families Policy Requirements.
Visit the Manage Applications page under AppDiscovery in the AppLovin UI and select the setting “Please check this box if your application needs to comply with Google Play’s Families policy”.
You must review the age data of your users and identify any age-restricted users in your AppLovin SDK integration. For integration instructions, see “How to set GDPR flags”.
If you enable this setting then your app will not transmit the Advertising ID for children and users of unknown age.